# gvim code folding by clicking in margin

Tags: vim, folding

Is there any way in gvim to obtain a *clickable* code folding margin, similar to the one available in diff mode? Please refer the diff mode screenshots attached.

Note that I am comfortable using the keyboard commands for code folding, but sometimes clicking is more convenient.

I have searched on the internet and also here. I have only found material which explains the keyboard commands, but nothing about the clickable option.

**Edit** I use gvim version 7.0.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the clickable code-folding margin (not folded)][image: Screenshot demonstrating the clickable code-folding margin (folded)]

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but I would highly recommend upgrading to Vim 7.3. You're missing out on great features!

Comment: @Lstor I agree. Unfortunately, the IT folks at my workplace take their own sweet time to upgrade. I did try installing it in my local space, but got some problems. I _can_ resolve those problems, but haven't been able to make that my priority yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that folding has been set up for your filetype (i.e. you can use keyboard commands like `za`), you just need to enable the fold column with a specified width, e.g.:

```
:set foldcolumn=4
```

---

If you set this globally, it will always be there. If you only want to enable it for certain filetypes (that actually have folding), and/or adapt the width to the amount of nested folding, use `:setlocal foldcolumn=...` instead, and put the corresponding commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`, where `<filetype>` is the actual filetype (e.g. `java`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType <filetype> setlocal foldcolumn=...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On vim 7.3, `set foldcolumn=4` works. 
Thanks also for pointing out how to adapt the width. Unfortunately, I couldn't quite figure out what you meant by `and put the corresponding commands into `. I have `filetype plugin on` and have put `setlocal foldcolumn=...` in my `~/.gvimrc` file, but it displays an error `Number required after =: foldcolumn=...`. Could you please explain? I am still getting used to the etiquette here at SO, let me know if I should post this as a separate question.

Comment: Instead of `...`, put in the width (e.g. `4`) you want :-) Unless you want this globally, the `:setlocal` should not go into `~/.gvimrc`, but into the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` (again, use a real `<filetype>` like `java`; duplicate the file if you want this for multiple filetypes).

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I got confused. I thought `...` means that it would automatically figure out how many columns are needed (as opposed to hardcoding the width to `4`).